# Can JQuery and Javascript be mixed together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if I could use query and javascript together so I could select an element by class with the javascript and then use javascript to work on that element. Sorry if that didn't make sense. Here is an example:

```
$('.nav_flag').src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif";
```

Would that work, if not how do I get an element by class using regular javascript. Thanks!

EDIT:I know JQUERY is JavaScript but I was wondering if I could mix jquery selectors and javascript 'controller'-for a loss of a better word

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.  jQuery is a library that is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question as asked, there are several ways to take a jQuery object, i.e., what is returned by `$('some selector')`, and get a reference to the underlying DOM element(s).

You can access the individual DOM elements like array elements:

```
// update the src of the first matching element:
$(".nav_flag")[0].src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif";

// if you're going to access more than one you should cache the jQuery object in
// a variable, not keep selecting the same thing via the $() function:
var navFlgEls = $(".nav_flag");
for (var i = 0; i < navFlgEls.length; i++) { ... }
```

But you wouldn't manually loop through the elements when you can use [jQuery's `.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/), noting that within the callback function you provide `this` will be set to the current DOM element:

```
$(".nav_flag").each(function() {
    this.src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif";
});
```

However, jQuery provides a way to set attributes with one line of code:

```
$(".nav_flag").attr("src", "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif");
```

To answer the second part of your question, doing the same thing without jQuery, you can use [`.getElementsByClassname()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11) or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) if you don't care about supporting older browsers.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery **IS** Javascript. You can mix and match them together. But you better know what you're doing.

In this case, you probably want to use [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set value of attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jQuery, rather than mix the two here.

```
$('.nav_flag').attr('src', "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif");
```

In many instances, it is fine to mix jQuery with plain JavaScript, but if you have already included the jQuery library, you might as well make use of it.  Unless, that is, you have an operation which in jQuery would be more computationally expensive than the same operation in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking for quite some time on google and it gave me no results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jQuery too:

`$('.nav_flag').attr("src", "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif");`

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind that jQuery is simply a library built upon javascript.

for any jQuery object, selecting its elements by subscription will return the corresponding dom element.

e.g.

```
$('#foo')[0] // is equivalent to document.getElementById('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an index to the jQuery object to get the native Javascript object. Change:

```
$('.nav_flag').src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif";
```

To:

```
$('.nav_flag')[0].src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif";
```

To get elements by class name in Javascript you can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( 'nav_flag' )[0].src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif";
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you could use `.toArray()` to convert the jQuery object into an array of standard DOM elements.  Then either get the first element or loop through the array to set all the elements with the class.

However, you could do this easier with pure jquery with attr or prop depending on the version:

```
$('.nav_flag').attr("src", "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif");
```

Or use pure javascript:

```
if (navFlagElements = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_flag") && navFlagElements.length > 0) {
  navFlagElements[0].src = "images/flags/"+userCountryLower+".gif"
}
```